# Hide or disable back button in final view of navigation controller based app

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm creating a navigation-based app, and I'm wondering how to disable or hide the back buttom in my last view.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Already answer you in the comment of your previous Question

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;

    //Your other code


}
```

Comment: Even though you provided an answer in a comment, Jack-ham's posting of a new question is the correct procedure; SO works best when each problem has its own question and answer pair. When they are in comments, it's much much harder for others to find the information later.

Comment: Probably better to do this in the view controller's initialization method. viewDidLoad is meant for configuring the *view* after it was loaded - whereas the navigationItem is a property of the controller.